# Why is the deep sleep current of my ESP32 board so high (schematic included)?

Tags: esp32

Currently i build a small weather station that uses ESP32 based sensor boards for measuring temperature, humidty and air pressure.

I designed the board with EasyEDA and received it some days ago from JLCPCB. Now I measured the current when the board connected to a battery and is in deep sleep mode and I was a little bit shocked about the high value. It's about 233µA. I expected something about 20µA.

The schematic of the board looks like this:

[image]

Does anybody have an idea what's wrong in my schematic? According to the datasheets of the components (ESP32, BME280, XC6220B331MR-G) the complete deep sleep current should be much lower... When the board is connected to the battery, only ESP32, LDO and the BME280 sould be used. And the voltage devider, but it has about 7MOhm, so that cannot be the problem...

I wrote a small program that puts the ESP32 in deep sleep mode. The code for this looks like this:

```
    esp_sleep_pd_config(ESP_PD_DOMAIN_MAX, ESP_PD_OPTION_OFF);
    esp_deep_sleep(1000000L * SENSOR_SLEEPTIME);
```

I think this is the maximum deep sleep that is possible with the ESP32

Thanks for any help
Harald

Comment: Your question belong to [electronics stack exchange]() as Stack Overflow is for programming related question. Other than the  two line of codes, did you do `WiFi.disconnect(true);`, `WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);`, `esp_wifi_stop()`, `btStop();`, 
`esp_bt_controller_disable();` and `adc_power_off();` before go into deep sleep?  ESP32 deep sleep power consumption could varies between 10uA to 150uA depend on what have been shut downed. Running at 80MHz vs 240MHz also help.  On your comment "I expected something about 20µA", if I read the LDO datasheet correctly, the supply current is already 50uA.